# What is the REGEX for a number followed by a period?

Tags: regex

EG something of the form: `12.` or `1.` or `143.`
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is it:

```
^\d+\.$
```

Comment: In general, you can put a period literal in a regex by escaping it with a backslash.

Comment: If "number followed by a period" means "string of digits 0-9 followed by a period", then this is a great answer (but I don't see anything in the question to justify the ^ and $ anchors).  Depending on context, "4e-3" is a number, as is "0xdeadbeef", and "3/4".  The question is ill formed.

Comment: Well, that's why I put some examples in the question. If I wanted base 16, exponents, fractions ect, I would have been more specific. Regardless I'll try and be more exact next time (I don't have much call to use REGEX so it's pretty poor.)

Comment: Sometimes you'll see `[.]`, it has the same effect as `\.`.

Comment: Some older implementations of regex don't have the `\d` character class.  `[0-9]` is a bit more universal.

Answer (score 15):

The following will match all of your examples, and should work with any regex implementation:

```
[0-9]+\.
```

Comment: Sure, it works with most modern regex engines and programs using POSIX extended RE (bash, egrep), but won't work with programs using POSIX basic RE (expr, grep, sed, vi): those require `[0-9]\+\.`.