# Specific Python pattern for the string that can help to slice

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am looking for the pattern which helps me to slice a string. The string is something like this:

```
text = '1. first slice 2. second slice 3. slice number 3 4. the next one
 5 that will not work but belong to no four 5. and this should be 5 and
 so one...'
```

I want to get this:

1. first slice
2. second slice
3. slice number 3
4. the next one 5 that will not work but belong to no four
5. and this should be 5 and so on...

I hope you have got the idea.

What I have examined till now is that I can use this:

```
import re

parts = re.findall("\d\\. \D+", text)
```

That works good until it encounter single number.
I know that *\D* expression is non digit, and I tried to use:

```
parts = re.findall("\d\\. .+,text)
```

or

```
parts = re.findall("(\d\\.).*,text)
```

and many others but I cant find the proper one.

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260280/what-is-the-regex-for-a-number-followed-by-a-period

Comment: @MikkelBueTellus - I don't think that helps very much, as that's already being used here.

Comment: It would be so nice if `r'\d\. .*?'` worked. Everything else just ends up looking like a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead:

```
parts = re.findall(r"\d\. (?:\D+|\d(?!\.))*", text)
```

This matches a digit and dot, followed by *anything at all*, provided that any digits are not directly followed by a dot.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '1. first slice 2. second slice 3. slice number 3 4. the next one 5 that will not work but belong to no four 5. and this should be 5 and so one...'
>>> re.findall(r"\d\. (?:\D+|\d(?!\.))*", text)
['1. first slice ', '2. second slice ', '3. slice number 3 ', '4. the next one 5 that will not work but belong to no four ', '5. and this should be 5 and so one...']
```

Online demo at https://regex101.com/r/kF9jT1/1; to simulate the `re.findall()` behaviour I added an extra `(..)` and the `g` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Just split based on a `lookahead`.

```
 x="""1. first slice 2. second slice 3. slice number 3 4. the next one
5 that will not work but belong to no four 5. and this should be 5 and
so one..."""
print re.split(r"\s(?=\d+\.\s)",x)
```

Output:`['1. first slice', '2. second slice', '3. slice number 3', '4. the next one\n 5 that will not work but belong to no four', '5. and this should be 5 and\n so one...']`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
( #First group to be captured
   \d+\..*? #Match digit(s) followed by decimal and make it non-greedy
)
(?=  #Lookahed
   \d+\. #Check if what follows is digit(s) followed by decimal
   | #or
   $ #End of string
)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bC9qY5/1)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(\d+\..*?)(?=\d+\.|$)
```

*Python code*

```
import re
text = '1. first slice 2. second slice 3. slice number 3 4. the next one 5 that will not work but belong to no four 5. and this should be 5 and so one...'
parts = re.findall(r"(\d+\..*?)(?=\d+\.|$)", text)
print(parts)
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/ewKESa)**